# Why variables that I'm retrieving have to be static?

Tags: java, variables

I'm absolutely new to java, so sorry for my stupidity...
I have following code

```
public class player {

    float height=100;
    float basex=0;
    float x=0;
    float y=(Display.getHeight()/2)-height/2;
    float width=15;
    float speed=2.5f;

    public void drawPlayer(){

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(basex+x,y);
        glVertex2f(basex+x+width, y);
        glVertex2f(basex+x+width, y+height);
        glVertex2f(basex+x, y+height);
        glEnd();


    }

    public float getPy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return y;
    }

}
```

But when i use player.getPy() in main method, it says that the variable "Y" needs to be static... But I cant make it static because i have 2 players on display. I tried using player.y , its same.

What should i do?
Thanks for help and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the method using the reference to the object you've created, not the class name like:

```
player p = new player();  // Create a new player and call it p
p.getPy();                // Call the getPy() method for the player called p
```

Comment: well I tried, but when I change it to static, then i will have to change y to the static too... thats what I cant use, because I have 2 players. When I press for example key "W", then both of them will move  up and that's what I dont want.

Comment: @MarekSchubert Don't change it to static, but call the method using the object reference.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting y as a class field, while it needs get the height every time you getPy(). Instead you better put that logic in the function itself, which would give:

```
public float getPy() {
    return (Display.getHeight()/2)-height/2;
}
```

And ofcourse you'll need to have an instance of the class, and not just using it by

```
player.getPy();
```